# jQuery With WebSocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I have a little confusion in the following snippet. I am trying to make a jQuery drop effect with user input data. This is working but only the first value given stays for rest of the click.

Here are the snippets

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pretech blog testing web sockets</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/jqueryWebTest/websocket2');

        webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
            onError(event)
        };

        webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
            onOpen(event)
        };

        webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
            onMessage(event)
        };

        function onMessage(event) {
            alert(event.data);
            document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<br />'                    + event.data;
           // var myDiv = document.getElementById('dropDiv');
           // document.createElement(myDiv);

            $(function() {
                setTimeout (function() {
              var $dropDiv = $('#dropDiv');
              var mythis = $('#holder a');
              // get position of the element we clicked on
              var offset = mythis.offset();

              // get width/height of click element
              var h = mythis.outerHeight();
              var w = mythis.outerWidth();

              // get width/height of drop element
              var dh = $dropDiv.outerHeight();
              var dw = $dropDiv.outerWidth();

              // determine middle position
              var initLeft = offset.left + ((w/2) - (dw/2));

              // animate drop
              $dropDiv.css({
                      left: initLeft,
                      top: $(window).scrollTop() - dh,
                      opacity: 0,
                      display: 'block'
                  }).animate({
                      left: initLeft,
                      top: offset.top - dh,
                      opacity: 1
                  }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
             },1500);
            });

        }

        function onOpen(event) {
            document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = 'Now Connection established';
        }

        function onError(event) {
            alert(event.data);
        }

        function start() {
            var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;

            webSocket.send(text);
            return false;
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



</script>

<style type="text/css">

#holder {
 position: absolute;
 top: 200px;
 left: 100px;   
}

#dropDiv {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 background: #ccc; 
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
        <input type="text" id="userinput" /> <br> <input type="submit"
            value="Send Message to Server" onclick="start()" />
    </div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<div id="holder"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="main">Which ring?</a></div>

<div id="dropDiv">The one ring to rule them all. </div>
<div id="dropDiv">The one ring to rule them all. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

websocket2.java

```
package com.test.websockets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.SendResult;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/websocket2")
public class WebSocketTest2 {

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session s) throws IOException,InterruptedException {

        System.out.println(message);

       // session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);

        for (Session session : s.getOpenSessions()) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("<div id='dropDiv'>"+message+" </div>");           }

        // Sending message to client each 1 second

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen() {
        System.out.println("Client connected");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose() {
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
    }
}
```

What would be a solution?

Comment: Might be something to do with your setTimeout function not giving enough time for the input value to update after being clicked. It's tough to say without a working example. Can you further explain 'This is working but only the first value given stays for rest of the click'

Comment: when a value(e.g. xyz ) is given in the input field and submit button clicked for the first time it gives "xyz" as dropdown animation effect . But if in the second time xyz changed into abc , it does not take abc as an animation effect string. it gives xyz as animation effect string.

Answer (score 2):

try changing these:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Message to Server" onclick="start()" />


function start() {
    var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    webSocket.send(text);
    return false;
}
```

to:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send Message to Server" />


function start() {
    var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    webSocket.send(text);
    return false;
}

var subm = document.getElementById("submitButton");
subm.addEventListener("click", start, false);
```

Comment: in browser console it is giving .  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: I noticed I forgot a closing semicolon on the last statement, did you see that as well? Here's a working example of the base idea https://jsfiddle.net/7yzuLfxj/

The problem is, you're setting the text input value once on load, then when you rerun the start function, it's not regenerating the new value- it's using the old, original value. The method I linked above creates a listener for the submit button and recaptures the text input value on each click.

Comment: No Man. That's not giving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are using same Id for your dropDivs:

```
<div id="dropDiv">The one ring to rule them all. </div>
<div id="dropDiv">The one ring to rule them all. </div>
```

here :

```
  var $dropDiv = $('#dropDiv');
  var mythis = $('#holder a');
```

You excpect that all your dropDivs would get the drop annimation, Unfortunately only the first element with id "dropDiv" will be animated.

Try to use class instead for selecting your html elements.